# Ways to switch views by swipe

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I'm building iphone app that display news articles.

For reading one article, I have a view with UITableView in it, that display the contents of the article.

What I need :
I want the user to be able to swipe to the next article with his finger, and the effect will be like the pageControl sample of apple, or like swiping between picture.(moving back and forth visual effect)

Questions :
The only way to do it, is with UIScrollView and "pages",
or there is simple way that include detecting swipe + manipulate switch effect + pushing view controller ?

Other direction that also I thought about is if I can create one view with one horizontal tableview, each cell will show one article, and the user will swipe to move to the next cell.

BTW- fox news app for the iphone has this feature, but it seems they use "page control" solution.

Any info will help.

Answer (score 7):

page control is not the only solution i think.
Imagine you got to views in your viewController and then when you detect the swipe and its direction,
all you have to is :

1. Add the content to the view that will appear
2. Add the view as a subview of your view controller
3. Place that view on the correct side (on the left if the user swipes to the right)
4. Finally animate the views moves (position) to the correct direction

and you're done...

Here is an example :

```
// in your uiviewcontroller subclass
UIVIew *viewOne, *viewTwo;

-(void)swipeFromView:(UIVIew *)visibleView
              toView:(UIView *)pushingView
           direction:(UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection)aDirection {
    // assuming the content of pushingView already set
    CGPoint visibleViewCenter = [visibleView center]; // register the center
    CGRect visibleViewFrame = [visibleView frame];
    CGPoint pushingViewCenter, visibleViewNewCenter;

    visibleViewNewCenter.y = visibleViewCenter.y;
    pushingViewCenter.y = visibleViewCenter.y;

    // I use 2 here, but you would make more calculations
    pushingViewCenter.x = 2 * visibleViewFrame.width;
    visibleViewNewCenter.x = -1 * 2 * visibleViewFrame.width;
    // reversing x if direction is right
    if(aDirection == UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight) {
        pushingViewCenter.x *= -1;
        visibleViewNewCenter.x *= -1;
    }
    // once the tmp center for pushingView is calculated
    // set it, and run the animation
    [pushingView setCenter:pushingViewCenter];
    [UIVIew animateWithDuration:theDurationYouWant
                     animations:^{
        [visibleView setCenter:visibleViewNewCenter];
        [pushingView setCenter:visibleViewCenter];
    }];
}

// somewhere else, you handle the swipe
-(void)handleSwipeGesture:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer *)sender {
    // set content, etc
    [self swipeFromView:viewOne toView:viewTwo direction:[sender direction]];
}
```

Hope this helps.